# Java - HTML tags for JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to get a JLabel to display new line characters by using HTML tags.  But the text I want is obtained from a method.  Here's the line of code:

```
myLabel.setText("<html><pre>myCart.toString()</pre></html>");
```

But, this literally sets the text of the label to `myCart.toString()`, not to the String that is returned by the method.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
myLabel.setText("<html><pre>" + myCart.toString() + "</pre></html>");
```

or just:

```
myLabel.setText("<html><pre>" + myCart + "</pre></html>");
```

since `toString()` will be called implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

```
   myLabel.setText(MessageFormat.format("<html><pre>{0}</pre></html>",myCart.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

"

```
myCart.toString()
```

"

should be

"

```
" + myCart.toString()+ "
```

"

But I am only repeating what Eng.Fouad said

Comment: well .. you noticed that you are repeating .. please don't :-)